# Should this display logic live in the ViewModel or in a mapping layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I've recently started on an MVC project, and right now it seems like every 5 minutes I'm facing large pivotal design decisions on how I want to go with this thing. Always the way, right?

I have decided to keep my domain model classes entirely out of Views; it will lead to a large amount of similar-looking ViewModels but using AutoMapper I don't think it will be a problem, and I think it is a nice clean approach.

However, my latest debate surrounds display logic. Say I have a model `MyData` with a property of type `Status`. This is an enum like the following:

```
public enum Status {
   Ok,
   NotTooGreat,
   CouldBeBetter,
   Awful
}
```

In a view, when I am rendering this model, I would like to output the status and additionally colour the output according to how bad the situation is. e.g. If it's `Ok`, I'll show green, if it's `NotTooGreat` or `CouldBeBetter` than yellow, otherwise red for `Awful`.

Where should this logic live? Ultimately the colour choice itself will be within the View (e.g. determine what css class to output, that class controls the colour), but determining what the state is at all is a decision that I don't think should be in the view. Possible options are:

1. Use DataAnnotations in a custom ViewModel class, e.g.

   ```
   public class MyDataViewModel {
       /* Amongst other MyData properties required... */
       public StatusViewModel Status; 
   }

   public enum StatusViewModel {
       [StatusDisplay(DisplayState.Ok)]
       Ok,
       [StatusDisplay(DisplayState.Warning)]
       NotTooGreat,
       [StatusDisplay(DisplayState.Warning)]
       CouldBeBetter,
       [StatusDisplay(DisplayState.Error)]
       Awful
   }
   ```

   This means my mapping is fairly dumb and can just map the enums over by value. The View would then rely on a HtmlHelper to alter the output according to the DataAnnotation. This seems fairly straight-forward, but is this putting too much "business" logic in the ViewModel? That said, isn't this just a UI concern so it's entirely valid for the ViewModel to define what the display state is? Could I potentially end up with a ton of custom DataAnnotations this way? Could these not get bloated, if I needed to also state which actions could be performed by a user according to the current state?
2. Keep the ViewModel simple, and rely on Mapping code to house the logic:

   ```
   public class MyDataViewModel {
        /* Amongst other MyData properties required... */
        public string StatusText; 
        public DisplayState Status;
   }
   ```

   This means the ViewModel has no knowledge about what state is tied to what DisplayState, it just knows what different DisplayStates there could be (i.e. Ok, Warning or Error). However this requires that logic to then sit within mapping code which doesn't feel like "mapping" to me - until now the maps between Model + ViewModel have been pretty straight-forwards calls by the Controller - but perhaps that's an unnecessary fear?
3. This *should* be in the view, the ViewModel should stay the same as the Model and then some code either in the View or an HtmlHelper for it will decide what class to output, based on what the `Status` is.

I think I am leaning towards number 1, but I would appreciate the views of others. One thing that comes to mind is that this is quite a simple example, but what if the View was much more complicated? Say, if `MyData` has a status of `Ok`, we wanted to display many more properties from the `MyData` Model to the user, or pull data in from other Model classes too?

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case I think that 3. is easier - leave a `Status` enum property on the view model and have a custom helper that will format it. I don't like 1. because you are duplicating the same enum and you could potentially end up with lots of data annotations. It seems unnecessary.

By the way 2. also seems a good option. You shouldn't be concerned about putting the conversion in the mapping logic.

Comment: Given the decision to not let domain model objects leak into Views, wouldn't that Status enum need to be duplicated anyway? 3 was based on that same `StatusViewModel` being created, just without annotations.